# How can I export a shapefile to netCDF?

Tags: shapefile, convert, netcdf

I have a shapefile of the worlds biomes

- [Terrestrial Ecoregional Boundaries Shapefile (TNC), 12/14/09, 50MB download](http://conserveonline.org/workspaces/ecoregional.shapefile/documents/terrestrial-ecoregional-boundaries-tnc/) from available from http://conserveonline.org/workspaces/ecoregional.shapefile

I would like to export it as a raster file; preferably a netCDF file with the [MsTMIP format](http://nacp.ornl.gov/mast-dc/MsTMIP.shtml) standard.

Ultimately, I could work with a netCDF that keeps metadata from the shapefile, or even a csv with no metadata. I can generate the .csv myself, but I expect that existing tools will do much of the work for me. Do they exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert it to GMT vector format, and then convert it using [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) to netCDF with all metadata saved.

Comment: Thanks - I'll let you know how it goes; I am glad to see that GMT5 is released under LGPL, since it is compatible with my BSD license.